# Can one-electron world theory be revived if the Sakharov's conditions are completely met?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, antimatter, cpt-symmetry, baryogenesis

Regarding that people object about the matter antimatter balance in the one-electron world theory to discard it, can it be once more revived if the Sakharov's conditions are met so that the matter antimatter imbalance can naturally emerge from a balanced world?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the one electron theory has nothing to do with Sakharov's conditions. The one electron theory requires the same number of electrons and positrons at all times. Regardless of whether or not  Sakharov's conditions are met, the fact that there is not now an equal number immediately falsifies the one electron theory.